MPPT setpoint buck battery charger IC operation and input/output voltage
I am trying to understand how CN3795 by Consonance works. CN3795 is

a PWM switch-mode multi-chemistry battery charger controller that can
be powered by photovoltaic cell with maximum power point tracking
function using few external components


The IC is supposed to keep the input voltage to the MPP setpoint, defined by R5/R6 and sensed by bit MPPT.
The battery is charged with CC/CV, max current selected with Rcs, battery voltage read by pin FB.
Is it that the input is held to the MPP setpoint only when charging at CC with a current smaller than the maximum (i.e. the input source cannot provide max current CC power)?
If that is the case, what is the output voltage in this state? Is it the same as the input, so the MPP setpoint?
Thanks!

Sorry, that was not very clear. I mean when the available power cannot charge at max current when in CC mode.

in any mode/case, the output voltage should only be slightly above the battery voltage on a charger, right?

How would the buck converter regulate both input and output voltages to two different setpoints (MPPT and desired output voltage) ? Changing the duty cycle of the PWM in pin DRV driving the mosfet M1 should directly affect both input and output voltages, no ?

it regulates the input voltage by only loading the PV so hard that it sags to just below the MPP. It limits the output voltage like a regular CC+CV SMPS. Since it has current multiplication (including by <1), it can deliver any output voltage with current limited by (input power) / output voltage. It's basically a regular SMPS with feedback from the input AND output instead of just the output. That why they usually use an MCU to software drive everything instead of using a traditional SMPS driver chip.

How can it control both input and output voltage with a single mosfet ? You either control one, or the other. So you either control the output voltage, or the input one and run at MPP.

What you are saying is true, it is not a real MPPT but a fixed one which is only optimal in ideal circumstances. I still do not understand how the controller could control both Vb and Vp at the same time

You had a few questions, and they not only show your confusion, but they confuse others as well.
The simplest way to look at it is this:

ALL of those setpoints - the minimum MPPT voltage, the maximum current through the Rcs and the maximum battery voltage - are simply the points at which the negative feedback circuit starts limiting the duty cycle of the switching transistor/MOSFET.

If the solar panel supplies more current than is needed for charging the battery, then the converter works just like a regular or standard CV/CC buck converter, reducing duty cycle only when the current reaches the limit set by Rcs or when the output voltage (at the battery) reaches the maximum set battery voltage defined by R1 and R2.

The point at which the MPPT input starts reducing the duty cycle is when the solar panel produces less current than is needed to maintain either the maximum charging current (CC point) or the maximum battery voltage (CV point, at which the charging current drops to that needed to maintain the maximum set battery voltage).
(As you know, a solar panel will produce less current when less
sunlight is hitting it, due to the Sun being lower on the horizon, a
cloudy weather, a shade covering the panel or otherwise the angle of
sunlight hitting the panel is below 90 degrees or the sunlight
intensity being weakened.)

MPPT takes priority over the CC and CV setting, so even when those two are not reached, the controller will reduce the duty cycle if the input voltage (solar panel voltage) starts falling below the set MPPT value.

There are two reasons for limiting the current before the solar panel voltage falls below the set MPPT value:

If the panel is overloaded, its voltage will drop too low to keep the buck converter working properly, making it either just stay on (100% duty cycle), or keep starting and stopping, leading to unstable operation.

If the panel is loaded more than it can supply, its voltage will drop close to the battery voltage (plus the voltage drops across all the components in series between the panel and the battery: MOSFET M1, diode D1, inductor L and the current sense resistor Rcs).
In this case, you will be using only a portion of the panel's available power, because power equals voltage multiplied by current and thus if your panel's voltage under load drops to, for example, one third (1/3) of its VMPP (voltage at maximum power point) then you are only using one third of the power it is able to produce at that moment.
The buck converter also acts like a transformer or an "impedance converter" which converts higher voltage and lower current at its input to a lower voltage and higher current at its output, thus preserving the input power (minus conversion losses), but if its input voltage is close to the output voltage, then it looses its transforming effect and merely acts as a "feed through" line.




Okay so your reply validates my first question, but does not answer the other two. What would be the output voltage when the current is smaller than the limit set by Rcs, therefore the controller is running at the MPP on the input ?

the output voltage is always (darn close to) the battery voltage, otherwise bad things would happen or physics would be violated.

@Bobisnotyouruncle I apologize, my answer was not complete yet when I posted it. I have edited it and added more to it, so let me know if it's answering your questions.

@dandavis that is true if a battery is connected, but what if a motor is connected instead ? The datasheet mentions that in the absence of a battery the IC can be used as a voltage source.

for motors, the output voltage is <= the set output voltage determined by the feedback divider. Just think of it as a normal SMPS with CC+CV, but with one extra limit built-in that keep the input voltage from sagging too much or peaking too much.

@Bobisnotyouruncle I have finished editing my answer. Please read it carefully, it should answer all your questions.

The battery voltage determines the charging rate maximum. PV voltage is regulated for MPPT as I recall, at room temperature most PVs MPPT= operate 81 to 82% of rated Voc. Although this Vmppt drops linearly 10% when the Ipv drops by 90% might not tracked.
The load current is regulated by PWM at 350 kHz via L1 and low Ron switch to maintain this input voltage which is divided down to 1.205V to output CC or CV regulated below maximum sensed by both Iout and Vout.
If the battery voltage is below 2/3 of CV, then the charge rate is limited to 17.5% of CC, called trickle charge.
There are two conditions cut off;

<15% Icc power.
Power protection

There are more functions but this is how MPPT is regulated at the input and output.

The input is voltage controlled and the output is thus current and voltage limited. If it cannot supply idle current, it cuts the input off with diode blockage.  Simple. Any questions?
